# Android Set New Line And Length Limit To EditText

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext

I'm trying to restrict user from overfilling the UI by putting limit to the amount of new lines and characters.

I'm using the code below but the problem is the `getLineCount()` seems to be only getting the `\n` count instead of the line count. So user can still overfill if there is a new line without `\n` character.

So if the user would enter 3 lines of text and then he can still add 5 new line and he can mess up his and others UI. So how can I fix this bug?

Note: I've tried XML line limitation property but it didn't work:    `android:maxLines="5"`

```
     etDescription.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
                {

                    boolean _ignore = false; // indicates if the change was made by the TextWatcher itself.
                    final int DESCRIPTION_LETTER_LIMIT = 168;
                    final int DESCRIPTION_LINE_LIMIT = 5;

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
                        {

                            if(after > DESCRIPTION_LETTER_LIMIT || etDescription.getLineCount() > DESCRIPTION_LINE_LIMIT )
                                {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "beforeTextChanged: limit reached. After count and line count: "+ after+ " | "+etDescription.getLineCount());
                                    isLimitReached = true;
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "beforeTextChanged: limit NOT reached. After count and line count: "+ after+ " | "+etDescription.getLineCount());

                                    isLimitReached = false;
                                }
                        }


                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
                        {
                        }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                        {
                            if (_ignore)
                                return;

                            _ignore = true; // prevent infinite loop
                            // Change your text here.
                            if(isLimitReached)
                                {
                                    if(etDescription.getSelectionEnd() - 1 != -1)
                                        {

                                            etDescription.getText().delete(etDescription.getSelectionEnd() - 1, etDescription.getSelectionStart());
                                            isLimitReached = false;
                                        }
                                }

                            _ignore = false; // release, so the TextWatcher start to listen again.
                        }
                });
```

Comment: For length limit, you can set the filter with regex on you editText field

Comment: @Kavita_p Could you post the regex for it as an answer please.

Comment: Please try the following regex for limiting the number of lines, which you can use as a filter https://regex101.com/r/fuBP8I/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
  <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingStart="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:lines="1"/>
```

or you can do it in the code alternatively

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setLines(1);
```

you can read more on the doc  [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setLines(int)).

Comment: This function sets how many lines the edittext is going to be. It doesn't limit it.